# Existence of JPanel when reassigned in layout

Tags: java, swing, border-layout

I wrote up this quick example to see what happens when the value of an area in a `BorderLayout` is superimposed with new content (or replaced?).

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    JPanel add1 = new JPanel();
    add1.setBackground(Color.RED);

    JPanel add2 = new JPanel();
    add2.setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);

    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    pane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    pane.add(add1, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    pane.add(add2, BorderLayout.NORTH);

    JFrame main = new JFrame();
    main.setContentPane(pane);
    main.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300,300));
    main.setLocation(200,300);
    main.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    main.setResizable(false);
    main.setVisible(true);
    main.pack();
  }
}
```

What I was wondering is what happens to `add1` when `BorderLayout.NORTH` is reassigned?  Does the garbage collector handle it?

I would assume not as there is still a reference to `add1` inside the class `Test`, however I'm not sure if it is still considered part of the JFrame.  If I'm going to be replacing `BorderLayout.NORTH`, will I need to set `add1` to `null`?  I guess what I'm asking is if a layout reference is replaced, is the new value superimposed into that position, or is the old value replaced completely and thus no longer part of the JFrame.

Comment: The `add1` variable is no longer reachable after it's used in your program.  ("Reachable" is a technical term in Java, Google it.)  When it gets replaced in the BorderLayout, it's eligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per most similar questions, the Java API holds the answers. Here the [BorderLayout API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html) specifically states (highlighting mine):

> A border layout lays out a container, arranging and resizing its components to fit in five regions: north, south, east, west, and center. **Each region may contain no more than one component**, and is identified by a corresponding constant: NORTH, SOUTH, EAST, WEST, and CENTER.

So by adding a new component to the NORTH section, you **displace** the old one, and it is no longer part of the GUI.

Comment: I see.  Sorry if this sounds like lazy research skills (or perhaps lack thereof), but I was trying to fill the gap between what happens when the NORTH component becomes unreachable in terms of its existence in the JFrame and the global existence of the `add1` instance.

Comment: @SmithNineSix: if the north component is unreachable, it will should be available for being GC'd.